# Catch click in UIWebView

Tags: ios, tinymce

I have an email form having some labels, textboxes and below them one webview(with tinyMCE editor). All of this is in a scrollView.

When I click on UIWebView(having editor), keyboard opens and hides the webview. So I want that when I click inside the webview, the contents should automatically scroll up.

I wish to scroll all contents of iOS screen upside on click of UIWebView. I googled a lot and found that we can't use UITapGesture or any click event on UIWebView.

Can I use the javascript event of tinyMCE editor: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.get

How do I catch click event on UIWebView? So that I can set the scroll content size.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only subj answer

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [webView loadHTMLString:@"<html style='background-color:blue;'></html>" baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tap.delegate = self;
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void) tap {
    NSLog(@"tap");
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```